# Grouping lists by a common element

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume we have a list of list as follows:

```
S1 = [{'A_1'}, {'B_1', 'B_3'}, {'C_1'}, {'A_3'}, {'C_2'},{'B_2'}, {'A_2'}]
S2 = []
```

I want to go over this list and for each set of that check whether a property is true between that set and the other sets of that list. Then, if that property holds, join those two sets together and compare the new set to the other sets of S1. At the end, add this new set to S2.

Now, **as an example**, assume we say the property holds between two sets if all elements of those two sets begin with the same letter. 
For the list S1 described above, I want S2 to be:

```
S2 = [{'A_1', 'A_3', 'A_2'}, {'B_1', 'B_3', 'B_2'}, {'C_1','C_2'}]
```

How we should write code for this?

This is my code. It works fine but I think it is not efficient because it tries to add set(['A_3', 'A_2', 'A_1']) several times. **Assume the Checker function is given and it checks the property between two lists. That property I mentioned above is just an example. We may want to change that later. So, we should have Checker as a function.**

```
 def Checker(list1, list2):

    flag = 1

    for item1 in list1:
        for item2 in list2:
            if item1[0] != item2[0]:
                flag =0

    if flag ==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


S1 = [{'A_1'}, {'B_1', 'B_3'}, {'C_1'}, {'A_3'}, {'C_2'},{'B_2'}, {'A_2'}]
S2 = []

for i in range(0,len(S1)):

    Temp = S1[i]

    for j in range(0,i-1) + range(i+1,len(S1)):

        if Checker(Temp,S1[j]) == 1:

            Temp = Temp.union(S1[j])

    if Temp not in S2:
        S2.append(Temp)

print S2
```

Output:

```
[set(['A_3', 'A_2', 'A_1']), set(['B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3']), set(['C_1', 'C_2'])]
```

Comment: @cricket_007 My idea was to begin from the first sublist of S1 and check that with other sublist of S1. If the property holds, append all those sublist together and and them to S2. But now, I should remove those sublists from S1. But, if I remove them, list S1 changes and I don't know how to iterate over a changing list in a loop.

Comment: Is speed/efficiency a concern?

Comment: @cricket_007 I added the code I have done so far.

Comment: @Grimmy Yes, it is

Comment: @m0_as Do you already know `A`, `B` and `C`? As in... do you know in advance what you group your arrays by?

Comment: @m0_as Can we assume that the subsets will contain the elements starting with same letter ? i.e. is the subset  {A-1,B_2} invalid ?

Comment: @AnupKumarGupta, yes we can assume they start with the same letter.

Comment: @m0_as Can we edit some lines of your `Checker()` function ?

Comment: @AnupKumarGupta That's just an example. So, I can say assume it is what is for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten (many ways to do this but a simple way is to use `it.chain(*nested_list)`) and `sorted` the list using only the property as the `key` and then use `it.groupby()` with the same `key` to create the new list:

```
In []:
import operator as op
import itertools as it
prop = op.itemgetter(0)
[set(v) for _, v in it.groupby(sorted(it.chain(*S1), key=prop), key=prop)]

Out[]:
[{'A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3'}, {'B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3'}, {'C_1', 'C_2'}]
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything other than replace `list` with `set`. Note: `set`s are not ordered.

Comment: This solution is O(logn*n) instead of O(n), which is could be if you just grouped with a `dict` (or `defaultdict`). Also, `reduce(concat, nested_list)` is similarly inefficient, since it uses list-concatenation, a linear operation. It's better to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`. Just pointing this out since the OP stated that performance is a consideration.

Comment: I didn't get your solution. Can you assume that the function Checker is given and update your code?

Comment: what does this line do? "prop = op.itemgetter(0)"

Comment: `prop` is a function that returns the property value of the `item`. Currently that property is just the first letter of the string, which you can use `operator.itemgetter(0)` to get. If you have more complex property definitions just change `prop`. Note: as pointed out by @juanpa.arrivillaga, this isn't the most performant code - the `dict` based approaches will be quicker. Note2: your checker function is very inefficient, just write your own `prop` function.

Comment: @AChampion if it is a function, what are its inputs? Checker function applies to two sets, but this prop works on one it seems.

Answer (score 1):

```
def Checker(list1, list2):
    flag = 1

    for item1 in list1:
        for item2 in list2:
            if item1[0] != item2[0]:
                return  0

    return 1
```

I have tried to reduce the complexity of the `Checker()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
S1 = [{'A_1'}, {'B_1', 'B_3'}, {'C_1'}, {'A_3'}, {'C_2'},{'B_2'}, {'A_2'}]
from itertools import chain
l = list( chain.from_iterable(S1) )
s = {i[0] for i in l}
t = []
for k in s:
    t.append([i for i in l if i[0]==k])
print (t)
```

Output:

```
[['B_1', 'B_3', 'B_2'], ['A_1', 'A_3', 'A_2'], ['C_1', 'C_2']]
```

Comment: This: `sum(map(list,S1),[])` is quite inefficient. Use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

Comment: No need for the `map(list...` just use `list(chain.from_iterable(S1))`

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a consideration, I suggest the canoncical grouping approach in python: using a `defaultdict`:

```
>>> S1 = [{'A_1'}, {'B_1', 'B_3'}, {'C_1'}, {'A_3'}, {'C_2'},{'B_2'}, {'A_2'}]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> grouper = defaultdict(set)
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> for item in chain.from_iterable(S1):
...     grouper[item[0]].add(item)
...
>>> grouper
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'C': {'C_1', 'C_2'}, 'B': {'B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3'}, 'A': {'A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3'}})
```

### Edit

Note, the following applies to Python 3. In Python 2, `.values` returns a list.

Note, you probably actually just want this `dict`, likely, it is much more useful to you than a list of the groups. You can also use the `.values()` method, which returns a view on the values:

```
>>> grouper.values()
dict_values([{'C_1', 'C_2'}, {'B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3'}, {'A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3'}])
```

If you *really* want a list, you can always get it in a straight-forward way:

```
>>> S2 = list(grouper.values())
>>> S2
[{'C_1', 'C_2'}, {'B_1', 'B_2', 'B_3'}, {'A_1', 'A_2', 'A_3'}]
```

Given that N is the number of items in all the nested sets, then this solution is O(N).

Comment: Can you assume that the function Checker is given (as I mentioned in my question) and update your code?  That property is just an example. We may want to change that later.

Comment: @m0_as then I highly suggest refractoring your code to make it compatible with the above. The best way would be for `checker` to *return the property that you want to group on*.

Answer (score 0):

Is your property 1. symmetric and 2. transitive? i.e. 1. `prop(a,b)` if and only if `prop(b,a)` and 2. `prop(a,b)` and `prop(b,c)` implies `prop(a,c)`? If so, you can write a function that takes a set and gives some code for the corresponding equivalence class. E.g.

```
  1 S1 = [{'A_1'}, {'B_1', 'B_3'}, {'C_1'}, {'A_3'}, {'C_2'},{'B_2'}, {'A_2'}]
  2
  3 def eq_class(s):
  4     fs = set(w[0] for w in s)
  5     if len(fs) != 1:
  6         return None
  7     return fs.pop()
  8
  9 S2 = dict()
 10 for s in S1:
 11     cls = eq_class(s)
 12     S2[cls] = S2.get(cls,set()).union(s)
 13
 14 S2 = list(S2.values())
```

This has an advantage of being amortized `O(len(S1))`. Also note that your final output may depend on the order of `S1` if 1 or 2 fails.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more verbose version using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

S1 = [['A_1'], ['B_1', 'B_3'], ['C_1'], ['A_3'], ['C_2'],['B_2'], ['A_2']]

def group(data):
    # Flatten the data
    l = list((d for sub in data for d in sub))
    # Sort it
    l.sort()

    groups = []
    keys = []
    # Iterates for each group found only
    for k, g in groupby(l, lambda x: x[0]):
        groups.append(list(g))
        keys.append(k)

    # Return keys group data
    return keys, [set(x) for x in groups]

keys, S2 = group(S1)
print "Found the following keys", keys
print "S2 = ", S2
```

The main thought here was to reduce the number og `append`s as this really cripples performance. We flatten the data using a generator and sort it. Then we use `groupby` to group the data. The loop only iterates once per group. There is still a fair bit of data copy here that could potentially be removed.

A bonus is that the function also returns the groups keys detected in the data.